# Kivy - Why does this unrelated (seemingly) change of button state affect the ability to clear a list? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

does anyone understand what's going on here?
the goal: There are many buttons. click two, they both individually append an item to an empty list. when len of the list is 2 (after 2 different buttons clicked)  if the two items are not the same, clear/empty the list. If the two items are the same, then clear/empty the list, and disable the two buttons. A memory game would be the idea here. The buttons start off blank, you click it, they show text, and that text is the item appended into the list.

The problem: If the two items appended match, it disables the buttons as intended but then it doesn't empty/clear the list anymore. Why? Also important to use screens as it's going to be a screen between many in a different app.

The relevant part

```
                the_btn[0].text = ''
                the_btn[1].text = ''
                pairs.clear()
                the_btn.clear()
            elif pairs[0] == pairs[1]:
                the_btn[0].disabled = True
                the_btn[1].disabled = True
                pairs.clear()
                the_btn.clear()
```

The complete code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


Builder.load_string("""

<ScreenOne>:
    StackLayout:
        Button:
            id: btn_1
            text:''
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.15
            on_release: 
                root.b1()
                root.check()
        Button:
            id: btn_2
            text:''
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.15
            on_release: 
                root.b2()
                root.check()
        Button:
            id: btn_3
            text:''
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.15
            on_release: 
                root.b3()
                root.check()
        Button:
            id: btn_4
            text:''
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.15
            on_release: 
                root.b4()
                root.check()
        Button:
            id: exit
            text:'exit'
            size_hint: 1, 0.15 
            on_release: app.stop()


""")

class ScreenOne(Screen):


    def b4(self):
        b4 = self.ids['btn_4']     
        b4.text = 'K'
    def b3(self):
        b3 = self.ids['btn_3']     
        b3.text = 'K'
    def b2(self):
        b2 = self.ids['btn_2']     
        b2.text = 'L'
    def b1(self):
        b1 = self.ids['btn_1']     
        b1.text = 'L'

    def check(self):
        buttons = [(self.ids['btn_1']), (self.ids['btn_2']), (self.ids['btn_3']), (self.ids['btn_4'])]
        pairs = []
        the_btn = []
  
               
        for x in buttons:
            pairs.append(x.text)
            if x.text != '':
                the_btn.append(x)
        for y in range(pairs.count('')):
            pairs.remove('')
        if len(pairs) == 2:           
            if pairs[0] != pairs[1]:
                the_btn[0].text = ''
                the_btn[1].text = ''
                pairs.clear()
                the_btn.clear()
            elif pairs[0] == pairs[1]:
                the_btn[0].disabled = True
                the_btn[1].disabled = True
                pairs.clear()
                the_btn.clear()

        print(the_btn)
        print(pairs)
    

screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='one'))


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager



if __name__=='__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

Why wouldn't the list clear after the buttons get disabled? :
I appreciate your input

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example.

Comment: @inclement Reduced the button numbers. It was already in the complete code. It's as minimal as it can get. Too many buttons maybe so I reduced the number of buttons from 10 to 4 to make it shorter. More visible with more buttons but the problem should still be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is not that the list isn't being cleared (it is being cleared), but each execution of `check()` adds them back onto the list. I think if you limit the initial compiling of the list in the `check()` method to non-disabled `Buttons`, it should work as you desire:

```
def check(self):
    buttons = [(self.ids['btn_1']), (self.ids['btn_2']), (self.ids['btn_3']), (self.ids['btn_4']),
               (self.ids['btn_5']), (self.ids['btn_6'])]
    pairs = []
    the_btn = []

    for x in buttons:
        if not x.disabled:  # ignore disabled buttons
            pairs.append(x.text)
            if x.text != '':
                the_btn.append(x)
```